# Passing arrays between functions in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, class, phpexcel

I'm new to PHP and I am reading data from an excel spreadsheet and I want to save each row as an array. After I have that array I want to pass that array to another function to "set" each array value with a specific title. I am unable to figure this out and was hoping someone could help.

Here is the first script:

```
    <?php 
include './Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include 'testCase.php';

class ExcelReader{

function getExcelFile(){
/*Get file from form*/
    echo 'Hello world' . "\n";
    $FileName = $_FILES["fileName"]["name"];

    /*Move file to server, if file already exists, don't move*/
    if(file_exists("uploadedFiles/".$_FILES["fileName"]["name"])){
        echo $_FILES["fileName"]["name"]." already exists";
    }
    else{
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"],"uploadedFiles/".$_FILES["fileName"]["name"]);
        echo $_FILES["fileName"]["name"]." has been moved";



    }
    return $FileName;
}

function readExcelFile($FileName){


    /*Create reader object for file and read object in*/
    $PHPExcelReader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($FileName);
    $PHPExcelReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $PHPExcelObj=$PHPExcelReader->load($FileName);






    $PHPobjWorksheet = $PHPExcelObj->getActiveSheet();

    $topRow = $PHPobjWorksheet->getHighestRow();
    $topCol = $PHPobjWorksheet->getHighestColumn();

    $highestColIndex=  PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($topCol);
    for($row=1;$row<=$topRow; $row++){

        $newTestCase = new testCase();
        $testIndex = $newTestCase->getTestCase($row, $highestColIndex, $PHPobjWorksheet);
        echo $testIndex."<- Test Index <br/>";
        $newTestCase->setTestCase($testIndex);
    }
 }
}

$newExcelReader = new ExcelReader;
$newFileName = $newExcelReader->getExcelFile();
$newExcelReader->readExcelFile($newFileName);

?>
```

Here is the second class that I am using to get the data and I'm trying to set:

```
    <?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Class for creating test cases to be sent 
 * into TestRail
 * @author Banderson
 */
class testCase {

    /*Function to get the data for each individual test case*/
    function getTestCase($row, $highestColIndex, $PHPobjWorksheet){

            echo "<br />";
            for($col=0;$col<=$highestColIndex;++$col){
                $ii=0;
                $cellValue=array($PHPobjWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col,$row)->getValue());
                echo $cellValue[$ii]. " | ";
                $ii++;


        }

    return $cellValue;

    }


    /*Function to set the data for each individual test case*/
    function setTestCase($cellValue){
                $title = $cellValue[0];
                echo $title. "<- Title"."<br/>";
                $type = $cellValue[1];
                echo $type. "<- Type"."<br/>";
                $priority = $cellValue[2];
                echo $priority. "<- Priority"."<br/>";
                $estimate = $cellValue[3];
                echo $estimate. "<- Estimate"."<br/>";
                $milestone = $cellValue[4];
                echo $milestone. "<- MileStone"."<br/>";
                $references = $cellValue[5];
                echo $references. "<- 5"."<br/>";
                $preconditions = $cellValue[6];
                echo $preconditions. "<- 6"."<br/>";
                $steps = $cellValue[7];
                echo $steps. "<- 7"."<br/>";
                $expectedResults = $cellValue[8];
                echo $expectedResults. "<- 8"."<br/>";
                $testSuit = $cellValue[9];
                echo $testSuit. "<- 9"."<br/>";


    }



}

?>
```

And finally here is the error message I'm getting:

```
    Hello world testrailtestinputV2.xlsx already exists
Title | Type | Priority | Estimate | Milestone | Reference | Preconditions | Steps | Expected Result | Section | Test Suite | | Array<- Test Index<- Title

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 37
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.3133  5664536 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- Type

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 39
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.3133  5664536 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- Priority

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 41
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.3133  5664536 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- Estimate

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 43
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.3133  5664536 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- MileStone

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 45
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.3133  5664536 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 5

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 47
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.3133  5664536 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 6

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 49
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.3133  5664536 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 7

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 51
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.3133  5664536 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 8

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 53
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.3133  5664536 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 9

Title 1 | Functionalit | 1 | | | | | 1. Turn phone on 2. Go to main menu 3. Push button | The screen should look like this | | | | Array<- Test Index<- Title

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 37
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.5097  5675280 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- Type

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 39
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.5097  5675280 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- Priority

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 41
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.5097  5675280 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- Estimate

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 43
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.5097  5675280 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- MileStone

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 45
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.5097  5675280 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 5

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 47
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.5097  5675280 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 6

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 49
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.5097  5675280 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 7

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 51
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.5097  5675280 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 8

( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/TestRailIntegration/testCase.php on line 53
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  635280  {main}( )   ../testRailScripting.php:0
2   0.0034  749112  ExcelReader->readExcelFile( )   ../testRailScripting.php:57
3   0.5097  5675280 testCase->setTestCase( )    ../testRailScripting.php:50
<- 9

Title 2 | Functionalit | 1 | | | | | 1. Turn phone on 2. Go to main menu 3. Push button | The screen should look like this | | | | Array<- Test Index<- Title
```

Any help would be wonderful! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `getTestCase` creates new array with one element and put it into variable `$cellValue` at each iteration. So, the array returned by this function contains only one element. You should fix it in this way:

```
function getTestCase($row, $highestColIndex, $PHPobjWorksheet) {
  $cellValue = array();
  for($col = 0; $col <= $highestColIndex; ++$col) {
    $v = $PHPobjWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col,$row)->getValue();
    $cellValue[] = $v; //append element to the array
  }
  return $cellValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for! Great help! If I could vote, I would :)

Comment: @Riateche, do I do that by clicking the green arrow? I'm new to this whole thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than read each cell in the row individually and build an array from those values yourself, you can let PHPExcel build the array for you using the worksheet's toArray() method

```
/**
 * Create array from a range of cells
 *
 * @param  string   $pRange             Range of cells (i.e. "A1:B10"), or just one cell (i.e. "A1")
 * @param  mixed    $nullValue           Value returned in the array entry if a cell doesn't exist
 * @param  boolean  $calculateFormulas  Should formulas be calculated?
 * @param  boolean  $formatData         Should formatting be applied to cell values?
 * @param  boolean  $returnCellRef      False - Return a simple array of rows and columns indexed by number counting from zero
 *                                      True - Return rows and columns indexed by their actual row and column IDs
 * @return array
 */
public function rangeToArray($pRange = 'A1', $nullValue = null, $calculateFormulas = true, $formatData = true, $returnCellRef = false)
```

Just specify the range using standard Excel range format notation such as A1:Z1